# Design and build a single board computer

Tags: raspberry-pi

I want to learn how to design and build a single board computer like the
[Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi). I saw a [DIY project](http://hforsten.com/making-embedded-linux-computer.html) on Hack-A-Day and design something
like the board in the DIY project but a bit more customized. Are the any websites,
books or tutorials to learn the basics and to design your own single board computer?

Comment: A single board computer is just like any _embedded system_, so I'd start there.

Comment: @MisterSorge  How good are you with PCB design software?

Comment: This question is really to big to be answered by EE.SE. From the [Help Center](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. ... Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: @NickAlexeev I have the basic skills

Comment: @Dzarda Can you recommend me something to learn designing embedded system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25742/designing-a-single-board-computer-and-getting-it-manufactured?rq=1

Comment: @MarkU I've already seen the question but it wasn't so helpful for me

Comment: As a start, you could design and build a micro-controller board, then and microprocessor-and-memory-and-io board with a TH up (bv. 6802, Z80, 8088). If that goes smooth you might try a small BGA chip.

Comment: I seriously doubt that the page you linked qualifies as DIY. The thought of soldering the BGA MCU alone give me the [jibblies](http://www.hrwiki.org/wiki/Jibblies).

Comment: What you propose takes more than basic skills.

Comment: @MattYoung But I need the basic skills before I start to make more complex projects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no good overall source on designing a Singe Board Computer (SBC). You might find some some specific help in manufacturers applications notes.

Develop your skills by doing small, specific, low-cost projects. IMHO start off small, and you will learn faster, with less cost or frustration.

(Telescope makers saying: "What's the fastest way to make a 12" telescope? Make a 4" telescope first.")

Start with MCU's which are simplest to get working. Then add external memory via an MCU with an external memory interfaces. Then ethernet and USB to get accustomed to them.

You might start with something where you might get lots of help, like an Arduino.

Plan to make several projects. Aim to get each one working properly. Expect that some might be hard, or not work. The biggest surprises are the things we do not imagine. Making something work properly, rather than partially work, helps find the biggest surprises.

Try to decide on a time-scale for a project, and stick to it. It is very easy to be over optimistic, then when everything takes longer, ignore that learning. IMHO it is better to set some target, recognise the things that took longer than expected, and learn from it.

Expect to take 6 months or more, so don't try to do too much in a single project. Even if you can do this full time, there will be tasks which rely on others, and take longer than expected. Because they are out of your control, there isn't much that can be done (other than throw money at them).

Unless you have *easy* access to test equipment, expect to spend more on tools and equipment than on parts and PCBs. Be prepared to buy development boards; having a way to test and verify behaviour saves a huge amount of time. Even for a DIY board, having a working comparison helps a lot, and pays back in unexpected ways.

1. Research what you can of existing designs. R-Pi is probably the easiest to find out about. Reuse good ideas. Manufacturers publish some application notes for specific part families which may help.
2. Increase your competence with a PCB design package. BGA packages are likely to need more than two layer board, so Eagle is less useful than other free alternatives. If possible find a few PCB design packages. Try them for a few days, and decide which you like, by trying to do a project. There are some guides on the net from manufacturers about how to design boards for MCUs or low noise. Make it more challenging; try to make boards with large and very small track/space in a restricted area. Practice on simpler boards should pay off later because you'll more quickly see how to place parts to make routing easier.
3. Surface mount soldering. BGA packages are hard. Start with similar pitch, but easier packages like LQFP, then move to UFQFP, then BGA. Design and make something, preferably using 2-layer PCBs, so that you can experience how to make, debug and get them to work. There are useful MCU's available in all those packages for a few $.
4. Cultivate a PCB manufacturer. Look for service with a good reputation, and with the specs you think you'll need. A low-cost, small volume, PCB service like OSHPark might be worth cultivating. I found laen at OSHpark very helpful.
5. Designing debuggable hardware. Practice. Review each project when it is complete and working. Each project will teach something. Keep a 'log book', or written record to remind yourself of what was hard, easy and surprising in each project, as well as how you did it.
6. Practice bringing up an OS on a SoC. How would you bring up e.g. Linux on a new board? You can practice that using an R-Pi or BeagleBone. Once you have this under your control, you could move onto SoCs which you want to use, or have much less support. (Or stay with SoC's with lots of OS support already.)

Edit:
If you have a *very clear* idea about which SoC family you want to use, *and* the same manufacturer makes MCUs in much lower-frequency parts (TI, STM, Freescale, etc.) then you *might* want to start with their MCUs. That way you'll become accustomed to reading their documentation, using their forums, and also you'll start to get a feeling for how hard their products are to use.

Comment: +1 for the great answer AND for having a great hobby (skywatching - assumed by your comment about telescopes).

Comment: @Ricardo - sadly not any more. I lived near Cambridge MA for a while, and attended [The Amateur Telescope Makers of Boston](http://www.atmob.org/) meetings, events, observatory etc. I now live in a city with few (astronomical) stars :-/

Comment: @gbulmer I want to develop my skills with the **Arduino Starter Kit**. Do you recommend me it to start with electronics?

Comment: @MisterSorge - what is it you want to do? It is a good place to start learning about electronics. If cost is no object go ahead. However, you might want to start with a smaller, lower-cost Arduino kit (Arduino clone, breadboard, wires, LEDs, 1k resistors $10), and figure out how to buy the rest of the kit your self *at lower cost*. That might cause you to investigate good ways to get parts in your location, how to identify similar parts, and what the parts do. Ask yourself, "if I take a slightly more difficult approach, can I learn more, or will it only waste time?" IMHO making a SoC is hard

Comment: @gbulmer Thanks a lot for your help!!! I know that making a SoC is hard but I want to learn to develop my skills ;)

Comment: @MisterSorge - I applaud your ambition. I think if you aim to make an Arduino, where you should get plenty of experienced help. Then try, maybe, a lower-cost, but well supported ARM chip (e.g. Cortex-M0/M3). Then a higher-end ARM, say Cortex-M4 with external memory, USB and Ethernet, and work through the different packages you will learn a lot of useful skills more quickly than starting with a SoC. Best of luck.

Comment: @gbulmer - that's great advice. If you want to make your own Arduino, the [Arduino Single-Sided Serial Board](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardSerialSingleSided3) may be a good option. You can etch and assemble the board easily. The down side is that you'll need a USB-to-Serial cable to connect it to a PC.

Comment: I thought RPi was closed source, or is it just the chipset docs that is under NDA?

Comment: I haven't checked if they are upto date, but this claims to be [Raspberry-Pi Schematic](http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Raspberry-Pi-R2.0-Schematics-Issue2.2_027.pdf). I am only suggesting looking at published stuff for examples and ideas. Or have I been *too* unclear? (I sometimes am, because things are clear in my head)

Comment: @jippie - Sorry I posted to myslef earlier. Doh! AFAIK, parts of the R-Pi chips are trade secrets. I'm not a big fan of R-Pi. IMHO BeageBone black is better in all contexts, and certainly better for my uses. I stopped watching R-Pi when Broadcom seemed to get out of the market.